# Another "Why is my Uva 3n+1 solution not being accepted?" question

Tags: c, ansi-c

Why is my solution failing?

http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36

I wrote this under the assumption that stdin was the source of the data.

I fully expect that it is a problem with my code, but I am lost as to why I get 'Wrong Answer' as the result. (Compiler Choice was ANSI C)

EDIT: modified to allow parameter 1 > param 2 (but now I get "presentation error" whatever that is)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  unsigned int p1;
  unsigned int start;
  unsigned int end;
  unsigned int current;
  unsigned int n;
  unsigned int p2;
  unsigned int max_cycle = 0;
  unsigned int current_cycle;

  while(scanf("%u %u", &p1, &p2) != EOF){
    max_cycle = 0;
    start = (p1 < p2 ? p1 : p2);
    end = (p1 < p2 ? p2 : p1);
    current = start;
    while(current <= end){
        n = current;
        current_cycle = 0;
        while(n > 1) {
          if(n & 1)
            n = 3*n+1;
          else
            n = n/2;
          current_cycle++;
        }
        current_cycle++;
        if (max_cycle < current_cycle) max_cycle = current_cycle;
        current++;
    }
    fprintf(stdout, "%u %u %u\n", p1, p2, max_cycle );
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void main`! **RAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH** `main` returns an `int`, usually 0 to indicate success.

Comment: so when they run it, they are testing that? While from the sounds of things, that's not best practice, however why should that matter? Care to explain why this is not best practice, or should your " RAAAAAAAAARRRRRRRRRGGGGGGGGGHHHHHHHHH" suffice?

Comment: Try to make it work when start **>=** end. And, yes. I believe failure to `return 0` for UVA problems triggers an error (not necessarily Wrong Answer, I don't remember the details)

Comment: @Daniel: It's probably not _the_ reason why it is failing for the judges, it's just that in under any circumstances, doing that is WRONG.  Could your provide a link to the problem?  That way we can see what the constraints and test inputs are.

Comment: @Jeff I think pmg is right about in his last comment, I'm just trying that.

Comment: Here's a couple of pointers: You are given some preconditions for the inputs. (e.g., numbers will be in the interval `(0, 1000000)`)  You shouldn't have to verify them in your code (save yourself some time on that).  In addition, there is no condition that the start value should be less than the end value so you definitely shouldn't be doing that check (as pmg hinted).

Comment: "Try to make it work when start >= end." this did it. Thanks!

Comment: Did it work with `void main` and absence of `return 0` in main? :)

Comment: void main without return 0 works and is accepted. I'll keep it in mind though.

Comment: How long have you tried to solve this? Fighting against WAs is half the fun.

Comment: `void main` is **illegal C** and invokes **undefined behavior**. Do not write it. Ever.

Comment: And this isn't a compiler error because...? I understand, however, not to do this. Still, rather than pseudo-religious dogma, explanations are great! Beware the undefined, because it might not work all the time. Nasal demons, and all that...

Comment: So, after further research, it's really illegal C++, not so much illegal C.

http://homepages.tesco.net/J.deBoynePollard/FGA/legality-of-void-main.html

Comment: @missingno - this was my first answer for UVa. I wanted to know that my output was correct, thought it did turn out to be a logic problem. Without more explanation than "Wrong answer", I didn't know if the output format was correct; they don't explicity define it.

Comment: @dwerner: To clarify, the C99 spec, section 5.1.2.2.1 says that `main` "shall be defined with a return type of `int`".  It also allows for `main` to be defined in "some other implementation-defined manner".  `void main()` isn't technically *illegal* but since it's implementation-defined, it's almost always a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if (start == 0 || end == 0) continue;` is unneeded the end condition is where both are zero so it should be `if (start == 0 && end == 0) break;` Also return 0 and make it `int main()` (at least in ANSI C I know if you dont return 0 its wrong no matter what). Also you're assuming i < j which is not always the case (as far as I remember). Good luck on solving it.

Comment: The last time it was just an extra space on the output string. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Yes that's another thing to watch out for, extra spaces/newlines.