# UVA's 3n+1 wrong answer although the test cases are correct . . .?

Tags: c

[UVA problem 100 - The 3n + 1 problem](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=36)

I have tried all the test cases and no problems are found. 
The test cases I checked:

- 1 10 20
- 100 200 125
- 201 210 89
- 900 1000 174
- 1000 900 174
- 999999 999990 259

But why I get wrong answer all the time?

here is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"

unsigned long int cycle = 0, final = 0;

unsigned long int calculate(unsigned long int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
    {
        return cycle + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n = n / 2;
            cycle = cycle + 1;
            calculate(n);
        }
        else
        {
            n = 3 * n;
            n = n + 1;
            cycle = cycle+1;
            calculate(n);
        }
    }
}


int main()
{
    unsigned long int i = 0, j = 0, loop = 0;
    while(scanf("%ld %ld", &i, &j) != EOF)
    {
        if (i > j)
        {
            unsigned long int t = i;
            i = j;
            j = t;
        }
        for (loop = i; loop <= j; loop++)
        {
            cycle = 0;
            cycle = calculate(loop);

            if(cycle > final)
            {
                final = cycle;
            }
        }
        printf("%ld %ld %ld\n", i, j, final);
        final = 0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "wrong answer"?

Comment: You mean the online judge says something is wrong, although your answers are correct? Oh, and please format your code properly.

Comment: Check for extra spaces/newlines in your output, apparently that can make a difference.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796933/another-why-is-my-uva-3n1-solution-not-being-accepted-question

Comment: You should link to the problem description so that people know what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 5):

The clue is that you receive *i*, *j* but **it does not say that i < j for all the cases**, check for that condition in your code and remember to always print in order:

```
<i>[space]<j>[space]<count>
```

Answer (score 2):

If the input is "out of order" you swap the numbers **even in the output**, when it is clearly stated you should keep the input order.

Answer (score 1):

Don't see how you're test cases actually ever worked; your recursive cases never return anything.

Comment: That's where the global variables (ugh) come to the rescue.

Comment: Not when @user1257966 assigns the value returned from calculate to cycle, overwriting whatever it had before.

Comment: Ah, but it returns only when 1 is reached, and that returns the correct value. I shudder to think how OP managed that, but there it is.

Comment: Consider calculate(2); this will call calculate(1), which will return the correct value, but calculate(2) will return who-knows-what (since it executes no return statement); since main overwrites cycle with this undetermined value, you end up with crap in cycle.

Comment: Yeah, right. It depends on the compiler using the same register to return in all calls. Undefined behaviour, but in practice, unfortunately you can pretty much count on it (or the test cases would already fail).

Comment: As they did for me (OSX Lion).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8706/discussion-between-daniel-fischer-and-scott-hunter)

Answer (score 0):

#### Part 1

This is the hailstone sequence, right? You're trying to determine the length of the hailstone sequence starting from a given N. You know, you really should take out that ugly global variable. It's trivial to calculate it recursively:

```
long int hailstone_sequence_length(long int n)
{
  if (n == 1) {
    return 1;
  } else if (n % 2 == 0) {
    return hailstone_sequence_length(n / 2) + 1;
  } else {
    return hailstone_sequence_length(3*n + 1) + 1;
  }
}
```

Notice how the cycle variable is gone. It is unnecessary, because each call just has to add 1 to the value computed by the recursive call. The recursion bottoms out at 1, and so we count that as 1. All other recursive steps add 1 to that, and so at the end we are left with the sequence length.

Careful: this approach requires a stack depth proportional to the input `n`.

I dropped the use of unsigned because it's an inappropriate type for doing most math. When you subtract 1 from (unsigned long) 0, you get a large positive number that is one less than a power of two. This is not a sane behavior in most situations (but exactly the right one in a few).

Now let's discuss where you went wrong. Your original code attempts to measure the hailstone sequence length by modifying a global counter called `cycle`. However, the `main` function expects `calculate` to return a value: you have `cycle = calculate(...)`.

The problem is that two of your cases do not return anything! It is undefined behavior to extract a return value from a function that didn't return anything.

The `(n == 1)` case does return something but it also has a bug: it fails to increment `cycle`; it just returns `cycle + 1`, leaving cycle with the original value.

#### Part 2

Looking at the main. Let's reformat it a little bit.

```
int main()
{
  unsigned long int i=0,j=0,loop=0;
```

Change these to long. By the way `%ld` in scanf expects long anyway, not unsigned long.

```
  while (scanf("%ld %ld",&i,&j) != EOF)
```

Be careful with scanf: it has more return values than just `EOF`. Scanf will return EOF if it is not able to make a conversion. If it is able to scan one number, but not the second one, it will return 1. Basically a better test here is `!= 2`. If `scanf` does not return two, something went wrong with the input.

```
  {
    if(i > j)
    {
      unsigned long int t=i;i=j;j=t;
    }
    for(loop=i;loop<=j;loop++)
    {
      cycle=0;
      cycle=calculate(loop );

      if(cycle>final)
      { 
        final=cycle;
      } 
    }
```

calculate is called `hailstone_sequence_length` now, and so this block can just have a local variable: `{ long len = hailstone_sequence_length(loop); if (len > final) final = len; }`

Maybe `final` should be called `max_length`?

```
    printf("%ld %ld %ld\n",i,j,final);
    final=0;
```

`final` should be a local variable in this loop since it is separately used for each test case. Then you don't have to remember to set it to 0.

```
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `This is the Hailstone sequence` It is actually the definition for the sequence used by the the Collatz conjecture ("the sequence always ends at 1")

Comment: @wildplasser The sequence associated with the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) is also called the hailstone sequence; I should not have capitalized the H, though.

Comment: I did know of the _popular_ name hailstone-sequence, but IMHO that is only commonly used in anglo-saxon countries. Cheers.

Comment: @wildplasser I see, but as far as I can tell this is an English language Q&A site. Now that I mention it, though, I don't see that as a rule in the FAQ. The only mention of English in the help files: http://stackoverflow.com/help/quality-standards-error :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a one liner just for reference

```
int three_n_plus_1(int n)
{
    return n == 1 ? 1 : three_n_plus_1((n % 2 == 0) ? (n/2) : (3*n+1))+1;
}
```

Not quite sure how your code would work as you toast "cycle" right after calculating it because 'calculate' doesn't have explicit return values for many of its cases ( you should of had compiler warnings to that effect).  if you didn't do cycle=  of the cycle=calculate(    then it might work?

and tying it all together :-

```
int three_n_plus_1(int n)
{
    return n == 1 ? 1 : three_n_plus_1((n % 2 == 0) ? (n/2) : (3*n+1))+1;
}

int max_int(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
int min_int(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{   
    int i,j;
    while(scanf("%d %d",&i, &j) == 2)
    {
        int value, largest_cycle = 0, last = max_int(i,j);
        for(value = min_int(i,j); value <= last; value++) largest_cycle = max_int(largest_cycle, three_n_plus_1(value));
        printf("%d %d %d\r\n",i, j, largest_cycle);
    }   
}
```